# How to add "float" tag exporting a TIF image with PIL?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, tiff

I would like to save a numpy array as a TIF image in Python (3.9), but I necessarily need the saved file to have the TIF tag `TIFFTAG_DATATYPE` (`333`) set as `11` which corresponds to a float image.

I am trying with the below code but it fails giving an attribute error for the value in the dictionary is an int.

```
rawtiff=PIL.Image.fromarray(data)
custtifftags={333:(11,),}
rawtiff.save('test.tiff', tiffinfo=custtifftags)
```

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

What should be the correct usage of this?

Edit: Apparently, `333` is not the correct tag according to [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/src/PIL/TiffTags.py#L165) (even though [this](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/src/PIL/TiffTags.py#L458) line creates a confusion). Therefore, the tag id is also a question.

Comment: tiff is though. there is some code in PIL to support floating point images, but I don't know if it is complete or well tested.

Comment: Please click [edit] and check/correct the information about the tag name/id you wish to set and its desired value. Currently it is the tag for *"Ink Names"* and clearly incorrect. Thank you. You can see a list of the tags like this `python3 -c 'from PIL import TiffTags; print(*TiffTags.TAGS.items(), sep="\n")'`

Comment: And you can search for any reference to `float`, `333`, `type` etc by piping the output through `grep` like this: `python3 -c 'from PIL import TiffTags; print(*TiffTags.TAGS.items(), sep="\n")' | egrep -Ei "type|data|float|sample|333"`

Comment: You've corrected a harmless spelling mistake but ignored the comments... ‍♂️

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was not so sure that it was wrong, that is why I did not change it. [Here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/src/PIL/TiffTags.py#L458) was the reason I thought it was correct, yet I can see that on [this](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/src/PIL/TiffTags.py#L165) it is written otherwise, in the direction you have pointed. I am re-editing my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Checking the source code for PIL and resources about TIFF tags on the web: there is a reference to 333 being "datatype" inside libtiff in PIL's code, as a comment - but everywhere else, including here:  https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/content/tiff_tags.shtml list tag 333 as being the "inkname" which is ASCII, and not a number.

It turns out that when PIL sees the tag "333" it calls the string encoder, which result in the error above.

If you are sure the "11" should be under tag "333", there are 3 ways to try it:

1. try to write it as a string with 2 characters, "1" and "1": just quote your "11" n your code and it should be going: `custtifftags={333:("11",),}`
2. try to write it as a Python "bytes" object where the first and only byte is the value 11 - PIL will read it back as a bytes object, but possibly the place where you are sending it will see the byte with the value "11" in the proper place: `custtifftags={333:(bytes((11,)),),}`
3. you can change in runtime PIL's metadata for the 333 tag, and it will accept a number. However, I could not find any spec saying if it should be a single byte, a short or a 4-byte int. This should do the trick, tough:

```
from PIL import TiffTags


TiffTags.TAGS_V2[333] = TiffTags.TagInfo(333, "DATATYPE", TiffTags.SHORT, 1)
# This will modify the PIL in the current process to interpret tag "333" as a 
# short (2 byte integer). Try "BYTE" or "LONG" 
# if you find out you need it with  1 or 4 bytes instead)


# the code as you put in your snippet will now work:

rawtiff=PIL.Image.fromarray(data)
custtifftags={333:(11,),}
rawtiff.save('test.tiff', tiffinfo=custtifftags)

# And upon reading the saved image, if PIL's tag 333
# is patched as above will show the tag there:

from pprint import pprint
i3 = Image.open("scratch/testtiffloat2.tiff")
pprint(list(i3.tag_v2.items()))
```

This prints:

```
[(256, 128),
 (257, 128),
 (258, (32,)),
 (259, 1),
 (262, 1),
 (333, 11),
 (273, (146,)),
 (339, (3,)),
 (278, 128),
 (279, (65536,)),
 (284, 1)]
```

However, as I said above, I am not sure if the "333=11" should be in this "main tgas group" or should be somewhere else.

Postscriptum:
on a last search on a "datatype" tag, I got to this reference:
https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/sampleformat.html
Which says the tag is "339", named "SampleFormat" and the valeu to indicate floating point Pixels should be "3". (also, it worked without any workarounds in PIL).

PS2: also, on libtiff C headers, there is no mention to `333` aside of "Inknames". There is this line referencing "datatypes":

```
#define      TIFFTAG_DATATYPE                32996   /* $use SampleFormat */
```

(SampleFormat being the above mentioned 339 tag)

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate message. I have tried all of your suggested methods but the result is still the same. And I believe you are right, tag `333` is incorrect and therefore, I have entered an edit to my post.

Comment: so, maybe it should be just 339, 3 as above?  can you check if your target system works with that?  (it looks like libtiff sets this up automatically) .